# Points in a sphere

Tags: perl

Hey all, 
               I am working on a algorithm regarding the surface area. I am using perl as coding language.

I am facing a problem in adding random points in a sphere. Given x, y, z coordinates for points. I want to construct a sphere around those points for a given radius r. My motive is to fill those spheres with random points in oder to occupy that space in 3d.

Kindly guide me through this one. I have no idea how to go about this one.

Comment: This is not Perl specific. I would rather look for an appropriate algorithm, e.g. first locate the center, and then construct the sphere using the point furthest away from the center.

Comment: You can use spherical coordinates, see for example topic [Sphere](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere.html) at Wolfram MathWorld

Comment: So you want to calculate a random set of points that are within a sphere within a given radius and centre?

Comment: Yes, random points that are bound by the surface of a sphere

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you use the *Monte Carlo method*

Suppose you have a sphere centred at (**X<sub>0</sub>**, **Y<sub>0</sub>**, **Z<sub>0</sub>**), and radius **R**

To fill that sphere with random points, generate a stream of random coordinates within a *cube* that exactly contains the sphere, and reject any point that falls outside the sphere

*`rand(v)`* is a function that returns a suitably random floating-point value between 0 and *v*

- #### Generate a point—a set of coordinates relative to the sphere's centre

  **dx** = rand(2**R**) - **R**
  **dy** = rand(2**R**) - **R**
  **dz** = rand(2**R**) - **R**

- #### Check whether it's inside the sphere

  **dx<sup>2</sup>** + **dy<sup>2</sup>** + **dz<sup>2</sup>**
    
  ≤
    
  **R<sup>2</sup>**

- #### Add the absolute coordinates to a list if they're valid

  *save* [**X<sub>0</sub>** + **dx**, **Y<sub>0</sub>** + **dy**, **Z<sub>0</sub>** + **dz**]

- #### Keep generating points until you have as many as you need

I hope this helps